# Copy particular data of fifth column after filtering

Tags: excel, qtp

With an Excel sheet of five columns, based on filtering the third I have to copy the data in the fifth to another Excel sheet.

I did something like this, but I'm not able to copy particular data of fifth column after filtering:

```
DataTable.AddSheet "Sheet1"
DataTable.ImportSheet "A:\Data.xlsx","Sheet1","Sheet1"
RowCount= DataTable.GetSheet("Sheet1").GetRowCount

Set objexcel = CreateObject("excel.application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.WorkBooks.Open ("A:\Data.xlsx")
Set objSheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

objexcel.Visible=false

objexcel.Rows(1).Insert
objexcel.Columns(2).Insert
objexcel.Columns(2).Insert

objSheet.cells(1,1).value="Minutes Interval"
objSheet.cells(1,2).value="Hour Interval"
objSheet.cells(1,3).value="Hourly Filter"
objSheet.cells(1,4).value="HH:MM:SS"
objSheet.cells(1,5).value="Weight(g)"

For i = 2 To RowCount+2 Step 1

objSheet.cells(i,2).value="=A"&i&"/60"
objSheet.cells(i,3).value="=INT(B"&i&")=B"&i

Next

ObjSheet.cells(2,3).autofilter 3,"True"
Set objRange = objSheet.Range("A1")  
objWorkbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Copy '--- to copy entire sheet data to AnotherExcel2

Set objWorkbookn= objExcel.Workbooks.Open ("A:\IntermediateExcel.xlsx")
Set objSheetn = objWorkbookn.Worksheets(1)
objWorkbookn.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste =xlValues '-- pasted here on AnotherExcel2
Set objRange = objSheet.Range("E2").EntireColumn                    '-- here selected 5th column entirely
objRange.Copy                                                       '-- copied 5th column
Set objWorkbook2= objExcel.Workbooks.Open ("A:\Result.xlsx")    
objWorkbook2.Worksheets(1).Range("E2").PasteSpecial Paste =xlValues '-- pasted to resultant excelsheet

objWorkbook.save
objWorkbook.close
objWorkbook2.save
objWorkbook2.close
objWorkbookn.save
objWorkbookn.close


Set objWorkbook = nothing
Set objexcel = nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mention you want to paste the only filtered data to do so instead of using this

```
Set objRange = objSheet.Range("E2").EntireColumn                 
objRange.Copy 'this will copy the entire column
```

Use this , it will copy only visible i.e filtered values.

```
Set objRange = objSheet.Range("E2").EntireColumn  
objRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy 'this will copy only visible cells
```

and paste the values the way you are doing.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I received an error saying, "Unable to get the SpecialCells property of the Range class"